# Corporate Github behind proxy: Received HTTP code 503 from proxy after CONNECT

Tags: git, github, proxy, git-config

I am trying to clone from a corporate git repo, but always receive this error message after a while:

fatal: unable to access URL: Received HTTP code 503 from proxy after CONNECT

I have the following .gitconfig file:

```
[https]
    sslVerify = false
    proxy = https://proxy.corpadderess:8080
[http]
    sslVerify = false
    proxy = http://proxy.corpadderess:8080
```

Answer (score 35):

If it is a corporate repo, you might want to ignore proxy settings. One possible solution to your problem is here:

1. Ignore proxy: `export no_proxy=YOUR_CORP_DOMAIN_ON_GITHUB`, where the domain name might be in the form of `github.acme.net`
2. Ignore SSL verification: `git config --global http.sslVerify "false"`

You could then clone the repo w/ `git clone YOUR_HTTPS_CLONE_URL`

Comment: On Windows, the command is: `set no_proxy=YOUR_CORP_DOMAIN_ON_GITHUB`

Comment: Excellent answer, still helps :)

Answer (score 19):

In my case I needed to disable both the proxy and authenticating SSL certificates, I don't really like this solution as it doesn't sit well with me - turning off verifying SSL certificates doesn't sound wise!

**But here's the command I ran to get it to work:**

```
git clone <addr of repo> --config http.proxy= --config http.sslVerify=false
```

Answer (score 12):

If you want to ignore proxy for a single git command you can use -c option, for example:

git clone http://user@yourcompany.com/repo.git --config http.proxy=

Answer (score 3):

you can add in your .gitconfig file for ignore your corporate proxy :

```
[http "http://proxy.corpadderess:8080"]
    sslVerify = false
    proxy =
```

Answer (score 3):

Even I had the similar problem while pushing my code changes into corporate gitlab after I set "HTTP_PROXY" and "HTTPS_PROXY" into my environment variable to use the proxy for accessing other sites that are blocked by the company. I ran the following command in `Git Bash console` to ignore the proxy before pushing the code and it worked for me.

`export no_proxy=YOUR_CORP_DOMAIN_ON_GITLAB`,

where the domain name might be in the form of **gitlab.aptask.com** (I didn't put any http:// or https://)

Answer (score 2):

sometimes previous proxy settings makes this kind of problem. I had unset some proxy settings and run the git clone/fetch again. then it was working.

```
git config --global --unset http.proxy
git config --global --unset https.proxy
git config --global --unset core.gitproxy
```

Answer (score 1):

If the repository is on GitLab, you must be a member of the Group or of the project ( see https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-on-the-Server-GitLab ).

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue and don't want to bypass SSL verification.

I make it work thanks to these steps (Windows):

**1. Launch in a console :**

```
C:\Users\ME>nslookup gitlab.my-company.fr
Serveur :   ken45d45.ntkd0.my-company.fr
Address:  XXXX.XXXX.XXXX.XXXX

Réponse ne faisant pas autorité :
Nom :    zep150y1fv0.something-else-company.fr
Address:  XXXX.XXXX.XXXX.XXXX
Aliases:  gitlab.my-company.fr
```

**2. In order to clone git@gitlab.my-company:project/group/sources.git :**

Replace by the original instead of alias :

```
git clone git@zep150y1fv0.something-else-company.fr:project/group/sources.git
```

Answer (score -3):

**use git ssh command**
git clone "ssh:/